# Handling bootstrap4 modals in Dart

Tags: events, dart, bootstrap-modal, dart-html, dart2js

I need to call bootstrap modals from Dart code and this is what I've tried (using the `js` library):

```
@JS('jQuery')
class jQuery {

  @JS()
  jQuery(obj);

  @JS('modal')
  external dynamic modal(func);
}

class Modal extends jQuery {

  Modal(obj) : super(obj);

  dynamic toggle() => super.modal('toggle');
  dynamic show() => super.modal('show');
  dynamic hide() => super.modal('hide');
  dynamic handleUpdate() => super.modal('handleUpdate');
  dynamic dispose() => super.modal('dispose');

}
```

in that code if I use the jQuery class directly I get no issues (`jQuery.modal('show')`) but if I use the `Modal` methods i.e.:

```
Modal modal = Modal('#myModal');
modal.toggle();
```

I will get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined (NullError)` .

The javascript the code is `jQuery('#myModal').modal(func)`

My second issue is how to hook a custom event for example: `show.bs.modal` in jQuery I would use `.on(...)` but in Dart I have no clue, I've used `element.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', onModalShown)` but it isn't triggered and I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you defined the jquery class but you need to get it from the window and you also need to defined you modal using @JS annotation, I don't think you can extend the jQuery class

I would have done like that

```
@JS('\$')
external dynamic jQuery(query);

@JS()
@anonymous
class ModalElement {
  external modal(String call);
  external on(String event, Function callback);
  ...
}

final modal = jQuery('#myModal') as ModalElement;
modal.modal('toggle');

modal.on('event', allowInterop((event) {}));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but unfortunately it isnt working, the `ModalElements` methods don't do anything and neither throw an Error.

Comment: now it's working, but is it possible to add more methods like:
`toggle() => this.modal('toggle');` to the `ModalElement` class?